# How to enable drag-and-drop in(to) the navigation of the Windows 10 explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, drag-and-drop

Image of me not being able to drag and drop the file on the right into the folder on the left:

[image]

I **can** drop it into the folder above "(downloaded) setups and programs",
but **only** via the right window.

I installed this Windows 10 Home OS yesterday, and today Microsoft's Support couldn't help me. Online I found a "solution" involving the pressing of the ESC-button while holding a file, which apparently helped a lot of people, but it doesn't seem to work for Win 10.

To put it differently: Where can the Windows Explorer's drag-and-drop properties be changed?

Comment: That should work like you're trying to use it, and there's no option (that I'm aware of) that you could use to change that.  Can you copy the file and, navigate to the desired target folder and paste it successfully? If you make a new folder under "Documents" and try to drop it into there, does it work?  Does it work if you boot into Safe Mode?  How about if you create a new user and try it with them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of the side-effects of removing the Quick access section by modifying the Attributes registry value for Quick access shell folder.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}\ShellFolder
```

Setting the `Attributes` value to `a6000000` causes this problem. Check out the last part of this page for an explanation: [How to Remove Quick access and Other Shell Folders from File Explorer?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/remove-quick-access-other-shell-folders-file-explorer/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But the path is `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{679f8...`.

Comment: I'm sticking with 7 though I want to test a clean install of 10 and upgrade all the way to when the options become available in the Folder Options and see if they will do what they say they do.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the "Attributes" key from `a0600000` to `a6000000` and after reboot D&D into the navigation works as fine as before.

completely key was:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{679F85CB-0220-4080-B29B-5540CC05AAB6}\ShellFolder
```